# Sharepoint 2013 Sept CU failed

Tags: configuration-wizard

I applied the Sept CU on all my machines, I have about 12 machines. It worked on all of them but failed on two. All the machines have the same setting and are all identical.

So after I apply the CU, the configuration wizard keeps failing. What could be the issue?

Comment: Check the errors in the logs of Configuration Wizard. If they don't lead you forward, you can edit the lines about the encountered error to your question.

Comment: what failing means on 2 servers? did you reboot that server then retry to on those failing servers?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes I reboot the servers and tried it again. Still no luck.

Comment: what error u are getting? are those server part of farm with other servers

Comment: Nop they are not. But stopping the search services and running the wizard again was a fix. Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the roles of the two failing servers?  If search isn't stopped before the Wizard is run, it can fail.  Typically running it a second time after failure will work in that case.

Comment: The two servers are Dev servers just like the others. I was planning to go to staging and production after I was done with this two.

Comment: I meant what server roles?  WFE, Index, Query, App, etc.  Also, put the errors from the psconfig log in your post so we can help you.

Comment: No specific roles, developers use them for anything they want. Usually Query, and app.

Comment: But I stopped the search services and run the wizard again, that way it was successful. Thanks so much for the help.